# List of Keyboard Shortcuts for Tools and Actions in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, tools, shortcuts

I haven't been able to find documentation about keyboard shortcuts, or how to customize shortcuts for tools anywhere online, after half an hour of searching.

Frequently used tool must surely be accessible via shortcut.

Where can I find a list of the keyboard shortcuts for Inkscape?

Comment: Pressing `F1` did not do the job?

Comment: It did! Thank you so much! By searching for 'Inkscape select F1' I found [this](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/keys048.html) page of shortcuts, which will probably be useful to anyone who lands on this question in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [**official and comprehensive list of all keyboard shortcuts for Inkscape**](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/keys048.html).